Macos v14.0 Java version is jdk8 but jdk17 take effect when run jdk1.8 application
Mac version is 14.0 (23A344),two jdk in my laptop, jdk1.8 and jdk7, install path is under /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk/Contents/Home
Background: I run a springboot app(jdk is jdk1.8) in IntelliJ IDEA 2023.3,while it shows the jdk version is jdk 17 not jdk 1.8.
Previously, it works and jdk is jdk1.8,after i run a jdk17 app in IntelliJ IDEA then the jdk1.8 app couldn't run.
My troubleshooting：

check sprigboot application maven config and IDEA compiler config, no issues;
execute java -verison output is java version "1.8.0_291"
execute /usr/libexec/java_home -v output is /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk/Contents/Home
search how to change /usr/libexec/java_home

install sdkman.
mannually add jdk1.8 and jdk17 into sdkman.



xxx@B-34FWMD6R-2127 JavaVirtualMachines % sdk list java |grep 'local only'
 Unclassified  |     | jdk17        | none    | local only | jdk17
               |     | jdk8         | none    | local only | jdk8


set jdk1.8 as the default jdk

xxx@B-34FWMD6R-2127 JavaVirtualMachines % sdk default java jdk8
setting java jdk8 as the default version for all shells.


check current active jdk version

xxx@B-34FWMD6R-2127 ~ % sdk current java

Using java version jdk8


run jdk1.8 applicaiton in IDEA, but the error message is still the same as before.

Question:
How to run jdk1.8 application with correct jdk

I don't use IDEs but surely the Java version is set in the project properties, not read globally?

IDEA didn't auto-pick SDKMan's settings. Does your project use Maven or Gradle?

@JackyLiu Maven

@Rollsbean Please check this File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Runner to see if it's using JDK 8 also please check under the menu File | Project Structure.

SDKMAN! installs to .sdkman folder
SDKMAN! does not install to /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/. The default location is: ~/.sdkman
See Where does SDKMAN install packages.
For best results, delete all traces of your pre-existing JDKs before using SDKMAN!. Empty your /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/ folder, and the analogous one for your user. And then use only SDKMAN! to manage your JDKs.
Tip: To verify the location of your currently designated executable for java command, try:
which java


/Users/your_user_name_here/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/bin/java

Specify desired JDK within your IntelliJ project
As commented by g00se, your IntelliJ does not use the Java home environment variable.
IntelliJ uses:

An internally bundled JDK to execute itself (by default).
An externally located JDK to build and run your project, as defined within your project.

 To specify the location of the JDK you want your IntelliJ project to use in compiling & executing your app, see the manual and video: SDKs.
Hopefully you are using a dependency-management and build tool like Maven or Gradle (or similar) to manage your project within IntelliJ. Specify the version of Java to use in compiling there in the configuration files expected by those tools.
